# Jquery find('*') doubling A tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm slightly confused by the Jquery find('*') on an element finding A tags. My example code is below:

```
<ul>
  <li id="cell1" data-link="Page 1">
    <p>Example text</p>
  </li>
  <li id="cell2" data-link="Page 2">
    <h2 class="story-body__crosshead">More from our Diet Debate series:</h2>
    <p><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-35150598" class="story-body__link">Read: Is breakfast a waste of time?</a></p>
    <p><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-35215686" class="story-body__link">Watch: How healthy is your breakfast?</a></p>
  </li>
  <li id="cell3" data-link="Page 3">Cell 3</li>
  <li id="cell4" data-link="Page 4">Cell 4</li>
</ul>
```

**Js Code**

```
$(elem).find('*').each(function(){
   if ($(this).html().indexOf('breakfast') > 0){
       alert($(this).html());
    }
});
```

Alert is however alerting *twice* per A tag. It shows the inner text and the outer text (full a html). However I am relying on moving elements and replacing them so this code ends up outputting links twice on the same page. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Why can't you use `$(elem).find('a')`?

Comment: Your code is matching the `a` tags *and* any ancestors of the `a` tags because `*` matches all DOM elements within the `elem` (which is your LIs)

Comment: BTW, jQuery has handy pseudo selector for that: `$(elem).find('a:contains(breakfast)').each(function() {
  alert($(this).html());
})`. And for your info, this is wrong checking for string containing text `>0`, it shoudl be `>-1` or `>=0`

Comment: @A.Wolff: Snap! Was just adding `:contains` when you posted :)

Comment: you are lucky to have top users answering in your post :)

Comment: @ParthTrivedi: You mean *really bored* users :)

Comment: If `elem` is the LI, `$(elem).find('*')` matches both the **paragraph** and the anchor, and both contain the text `breakfast`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie naaah!!! but sometimes people stuck in the language of the answer.....;)

Comment: Thanks for the tips :) Silly question but thanks adeneo for pointing out that both elements are matched!

Comment: @Jai now you are also here. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is matching the `a` tags *and* any ancestors of the `a` tags because `*` matches all DOM elements within the `elem` (which is your LIs). In your example it will match the `p` tags as well as the `a` tags.

Use a scoped selector that targets only the `a` tags:

e.g.

```
// Elem here is the li about
$("a", elem).each(function(){
    if ($(this).html().indexOf('breakfast') >= 0){
        alert($(this).html());
    }       
});
```

Or simpler using `:contains`:

```
$("a:contains(breakfast)", elem).each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Note: Your code only allows for text containing `breakfast` but not `Breakfast` (e.g. if it was at the start and capitalized) as the check is case-sensitive.

Comment: @A. Wolff: Thanks for the edit. That > character came from a straight cut/paste of the OPs question! Should have checked the logic, but  even `:contains` will not avoid the problem of a leading breakfast (which would have a capital B if it existed) :)